# sendmail error while IPv6&STARTTLS configuration

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, ipv6

I'm configuring sendmail with STARTTLS(Client certificate) over IPv6 network.
When my client try to send mail, I recieved the following messages.

Client side :

```
Sending of the message failed.
The message could not be sent because the connection to Outgoing server (SMTP) example.com timed out. Try again.
```

Server side :

```
Jul 31 00:44:41 hostname sm-mta[16562] : u6Vh1c016562: [IPv6:2001:???:????::?] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA6-TLS
```

Following are related configuration (sendmail.mc)

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA6-TLS, Port=smtps, M=aO)dnl
inlcude(`/etc/mail/tls/starttls.m4')dnl
```

Edited related directory setting of starttls.m4 and gave decent permission

```
confCACERT
confCACERT_PATH
confSERVER_CERT
confSERVER_KEY
confCLIENT_CERT
confCLIENT_KEY
```

I have MX record for smtp server like

```
IN    MX  10  server.example.com
```

Can I get a guide for it?

Regards.

Comment: Your client must send to port 587, not port 465.

Comment: I tried to change port but it didn't fix. but log changed a bit.
sm-mta[16562] : u6Vh1c016562: [IPv6:2001:???:????::?] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to <<<MSP-v6>>>